# How to implement linear sort?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a sorting algorithm which works like this: For example, suppose the input is the list of integers `[4,2,1,3]`.  The algorithm performs the following actions:

1. Read 4 from the input. Since the stack is empty, push 4 onto the
   stack. (Current stack = `[4]`)
2. Read 2 from the input. Since 2 <= 4, push 2 onto the stack.
   (Current stack = `[2,4]`)
3. Read 1 from the input. Since 1 <= 2, push 1 onto the stack.
   (Current stack = `[1,2,4]`)
4. Read 3 from the input. Since 3 > 1, pop 1 to the output. (Current
   stack = `[2,4]`)
5. Since 3 > 2, pop 2 to the output. (Current stack = `[4]`)
6. Since 3 <= 4, push 3 onto the stack. (Current stack = `[3,4]`)
7. Since there are no more input values, pop 3 and 4 to the output.

Input values have been popped in order `[1,2,3,4]`

I tried to implement two functions for pushing an element and popping an element. I'm not sure on how to implement a temporary list as in the above algorithm.

```
stackPush :: a -> [a] -> [a]
stackPush x l = x:l

stackPop :: [a] -> [a]
stackPop l = tail l
```

I'm not allowed to use a Stack data type.

Comment: That's not really a sorting algorithm, as it assumes that you'll never read input smaller than the current top of the stack.

Comment: That algorithm looks wrong. In particular, consider the input `[4,2,1,3,0]`. You'll end up outputting the 1 before the 0.

Comment: (I believe there is a name for sequences that *can* be sorted using your algorithm; I don't recall what it is, though.)

Comment: A shorter example of how this goes wrong is `[1,2,0]`. After pushing `1` to the stack, you immediately pop it to the output, thereby committing to `1` being the smallest element in the entire list. Then you see `0`... which is smaller. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the List data type, and do a classic non performance:

```
sort [] = []
sort [x] = [x]
sort (x:y:xs) = 
 if x < y 
 then go $ sort xs ++ [x,y]
 else go $ sort xs ++ [y,x]
 where
  go [] = []
  go (x:y:xs) = 
   if x < y 
   then  x : sort (y:xs)
   else  y : sort (x:xs)
```

as an example:

```
sort [5,2,4,5,6,2,1,5,7,11,3]
=> [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,11]
```

Answer (score 0):

a direct translation will be

```
f [] = []
f xs = go xs [] []
     where go [] ys os = (reverse ys) ++ os
           go (x:xs) [] os = go xs [x] os
           go (x:xs) (y:ys) os | x<y       = go (pop (x:xs)) (x:y:ys)     os
                               | otherwise = go (x:xs)       (pop (y:ys)) (y:os)  
                               where pop []     = []
                                     pop (x:xs) = xs
```

but it cannot be called a sorting algorithm though.